# The color of the div is outside the margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, margin

I set the width of my page on 970px.
Everything is going well, even the paragraph is aligned within the margin but when I apply the color, it is outside the margin.

```
<div class="container">

            <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navegacion">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Cambiar Navegación</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand texto"><strong>Amixer Music</strong></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav textomenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Traductor Amixer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Yahoo Fail</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </nav>
            </header>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/amixermusic2.png" alt="AmixerMusic"/></a>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 alineado">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

// Not stuff like this which is a code comment :-)

```
html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #222;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 100%;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}


/*My personal css*/

/* Custom container */
.container{
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 970px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border: 5px solid #2E2E2E;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
           -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

.imagen
{
    width: 100%;
}

.navegacion
{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
}

.texto
{
    font-family: 'Nunito', serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
}

.textomenu
{
    font-family: 'Nunito', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.alineado
{
    background-color: orange;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;
}

.color2
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because bootstrap auto add `-15px` to left and right `margin` of `.row`:

```
.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Try to reset it and you should be fine:

```
.row {
    margin: 0
}
```

**[Demo](http://bootply.com/107640)**